# Denotation and connotation of the phrase

Tags: synonyms, syntax, semantics, structure, semantic-roles

> As doctors often do, I took a **trial shot** at it as a point of departure. "Has she had a sore throat?"

In English, we can understand this very easily but very difficult to explain "trial shot" in some other language like Urdu. As we (in Pakistan) are bound to follow Grammar Translation Method, it becomes far difficult to explain such phrases.
So, what other words can be opted to replace 'trial shot'? Is there any synonyms for this phrase to make it simpler? Does trial shot mean to make a guess here?

Comment: You may find it easy to understand but I am afraid I do not. What exactly is trial shot supposed to mean here?

Comment: "I made a guess" seems fine.

Comment: Presumably you mean **sore throat**? There is an idiom **a shot in the dark** meaning a wild guess not based on any information. However, a doctor's guess may not be as wild as all that!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "trial shot" is not natural English. It seems redundant, and is likely the result of someone speaking extemporaneously, rather than from prepared notes or in careful writing.

To "take a shot" means to make an attempt:

> **5 :** to attempt to do something successfully —often + at
> *// Take a shot at the math problem.
>
> // I never changed a tire before, but I'll take a shot at it.*

And "trial" as an adjective means to try something and see what happens:

> **2 :** made or done as a test or experiment

The speaker here likely had both ideas in their head while forming this sentence and both came out.

Answer (score 0):

“Trial shot” is a metaphor that has become an idiom.

I have no idea how the Grammar Translation Method deals with idioms.

The meaning is clear enough: “took a trial shot” means “made a reasonable guess.” There is no way to translate idioms word by word; you must translate the entire meaning.